# DataBricks: Cache Select on Temp Table

Tags: pyspark, databricks

How might I cache a temp table?

The documentation suggests it is possible: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-cache.html

Consider the following on DBR 10.5 and Spark 3.2.1:

```
%python
df.createOrReplaceTempView("changeset");
```

```
CACHE SELECT * from changeset
```

`CACHE supports only SELECT queries with optional WHERE clause, e.g. CACHE SELECT <columns> FROM <table> [ WHERE <predicate> ]`

### Edit

I have found that if you do ANYTHING to your data, like:

```
spark.sql("select distinct * from table") # CACHE SELECT will fail
# instead of
spark.sql("select * from table") # CACHE SELECT will work
```

Your attempts to CACHE SELECT will fail.

Comment: How about Cacheing the Dataframe and  creating a TempView out of it

df.cache

Comment: How do we know that this works?

Comment: CACHE SELECT is the DELTA CACHE. Which works with Parquet data.

The one I suggested above is  Spark Cache which does the same stuff but the implementation is slightly different and suited for all types of data files.

Comment: spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled")  will return whether  DELTA CACHE in enabled in your cluster.

Comment: So you can't cache select when you load data this way: `df = spark.sql("select distinct * from table")`; you must load like this: `spark.read.format("delta").load(f"/mnt/loc")` which I do not know why. Actually this is not even right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So despite the documentation having `latest` in the name, there is other documentation that shows the query should be structured like this (which works), instead

`CACHE TABLE testCache OPTIONS ('storageLevel' 'DISK_ONLY') SELECT * FROM testData;`

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-cache-table.html